Adding an unwanted number for a reaction
To describe multiple reactions, I add text using the command \intertext.
Doing this adds numbering to an empty reaction line which is unwanted.

How can I fix this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
    \intertext{étape 1 : formation du carbocation}
    R-X <=>[$k\sb{1}$][$k\sb{-1}$] R\pch{} + X\mch{}
    \intertext{étape 2 : attaque du nucléophile sur le carbocation}
    R\pch{} + Nu\mch{} ->[$k\sb{2}$] R-Nu
\end{reactions}
\end{document}


Some quick hacks:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
\noindent étape 1 : formation du carbocation
\begin{reactions}
    R-X <=>[$k\sb{1}$][$k\sb{-1}$] R\pch{} + X\mch{}
    \intertext{étape 2 : attaque du nucléophile sur le carbocation}
    R\pch{} + Nu\mch{} ->[$k\sb{2}$] R-Nu
\end{reactions}


\begin{reactions}
    \notag \intertext{étape 1 : formation du carbocation}
    R-X <=>[$k\sb{1}$][$k\sb{-1}$] R\pch{} + X\mch{}
    \intertext{étape 2 : attaque du nucléophile sur le carbocation}
    R\pch{} + Nu\mch{} ->[$k\sb{2}$] R-Nu
\end{reactions}
\end{document}


